# Using Python to call `ImageMagick`s `-coalesce` on a particular .gif via Windows command line

Tags: windows, python-2.7, imagemagick, command-line-arguments

How can I call ImageMagick's `coalesce` in Windows command line using Python, for the following command?

Currently, I am using the following lines to change to the Desktop directory, then run ImageMagick's "coalesce" function on a `.gif` file that exists on the desktop ("on.gif"). This command breaks the `.gif` file into individual frames saved to the desktop (off0.png, off1.png, off2.png, ...)

```
os.system('cd C:\...\Desktop')
os.system('convert on.gif -coalesce off%d.png')
```

but it is giving me an error: `convert: no images defined 'off%d.gif' @ error/convert.c/COnvertImageCommand/3235`. When I run this command in the Windows shell, it works fine. I think the error is in how I'm passing the `%` sign to the windows command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `os.system()` starts a new, separate process. So it is no use changing directory in the first and then starting another process which is running in a different directory.

Instead, you need to change directory and do your commands in the same process something like this:

```
os.system('cd somewhere && convert something ...')
```

If your *somehwere* has spaces in it, you will need to enclose it in double quotes:

```
os.system('cd "C:\Users\path with space" && convert ...')
```

If Python doesn't know the path to **ImageMagick**'s `convert`, you will need to put the full path explicitly, something like:

```
os.system('cd somewhere && "C:\Programs X86\Imagemagick7.0.2\convert" ... ')
```

Comment: That's helpful, I did not know that.  I'm still getting the "no images defined" error mentioned above.

Comment: Has your directory or filename got spaces in it? If so, you need double quotes (`"..."`) around them.

Comment: Also, you may not have the PATH set correctly so that `python` can find `convert.exe`, so you may need the full path, like `"C:\Programs X86\ImageMagick\bin\convert" something ... something`